# How to change successful flash message in Rainlab Blog Plugin while creating a post?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, flash-message

I am using October CMS and Rainlab Blog Plugin on my site. Whenever I create a post in Blog section in the backend, I see a flash message that says "Blog post created." As it appears right after I create a post, I need to know where I can find the method that runs this flash message. Searches in plugin folder didn't give any results,maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Defined inside the `FormController` Behaviour and it's based on the Model Name and the action that was performed, you can override this on the apropiated `afterX` method just in your model.

```
public function afterSave()
{
    Flash::purge();//clean the default messages
    Flash::success('Your custom message');
}
```

Remember to import the Flash Facade at the top of your file.

`use Flash`;

Also i suggest to use a language file to keep it clean

```
public function afterSave()
{
    Flash::purge();
    Flash::success('namespace.plugin.lang.code');
}
```

If you don't want to touch any Rainlab Blog files you can do it from another of your plugins binding listening the desired event on the boot event in your `Plugin.php` definition

```
public function boot()
{
    RainLabModelPost::extend(function ($model) {
        $model->bindEventOnce('model.afterSave', function () use ($model) {
            Flash::purge();
            Flash::success('namespace.plugin.lang.code');
        });
    });
}
```